# В консоли ошибка ValueError: "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'

Tags: python

В чём заключается моя ошибка? Первый `if` почему-то не хочет добавлять себе `else`:

```
colaa = 50
if Choice == 1: 
 colaa = int(input('Введите деньги. Кока кола стоит 50 рублей: '))
 money = input()
else:
   print("Попробуйте ещё раз")
if int(money) < int(colaa):
     print('Нeдостаточно денег')
elif int(money) == int(colaa):
     print('Вот ваша колла')
elif int(money) > int(colaa):
     print((money - colaa) + 'Вот ваша колла')
```

Comment: тут зависит от того, что вы вообще вводите. легче привести пример рабочего кода.

Answer (score 0):

```py
cola = 50
if choice == 1: 

    money = int(input('Введите деньги. Кока кола стоит 50 рублей: ')) 
    if money < cola:
        print('Нeдостаточно денег')
    elif money == cola:
        print('Вот ваша кола')
    elif money > cola:
        print('Вот ваша кола + {}'.format(money - cola)
else:

    print("Попробуйте ещё раз")
```

если `Choice` - не константа(а как я понял, ею она не является) - синтаксически правильнее писать ее с **маленькой буквы**.